# Typing localhost in the browser throws HTTP 401.2 UnAuthorized error: IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, localhost

When I type localhost in the browser, I am not able to see the IIS page that would normally show, rather it complains HTTP 401.2 UnAuthorized error. I am running IIS 7.5.

I tried changing the hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc to include

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

(without # sign)

Is there anything else I need to do to get this working. Please help.

Detailed Error Information

```
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    AuthenticateRequest
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x80070005
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot
Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User  Not yet determined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an authentication issue. What type of authentication is enabled ? How do you handle it ?

Check that **only** anonymous authentication is enabled if you don't need authentication. And make sure that the folder that holds your website is accessible by IIS application pool working thread.

Comment: Awesome, as soon as you specified it as an authentication issue, I realized what I was doing wrong. I didn't enable any authentication for Default Website in IIS. As soon as I enabled it, it just worked. Thanks!